# htaccess redirect HTTP_USER_AGENT but not the homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect google reffered viewers to a welcome-page , the point is that if google refferes to homepage it should't redirect to welcome-page , but to the homepage itself ..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !http://homepage\.com/
RewriteRule .* http://homepage\.com/welcome-page/
```

It seems that after %{HTTP_REFERER} htaccess does not check the not "!" and redirects all requests to the welcome-page, even redirects the homepage request to welcome-page.
So how can i redirect google trraffics to a specefic page, but when the traffic reffers to home page it shouldn't redirect.
as you know google may bring traffic to diifferent pages on your site, homepage.com or homepage.com/page2 or homepage.com/page3 etc. i need not to redirect the homepage.com.

With help of answer on this page and a little internet search this is the answer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/welcome-page/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /welcome-page/ [R=302,L]
```

infact the home page should be excluded like : !^/$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the correct RewriteCond. To redirect google referer requests to /home-page/ , you can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !welcome-page http://example.com/welcome-page/ [L,R]
```

Comment: it's some how ok or not .. as you excluded the !welcome-page, but i need to exclude the home page. i don't know why can't exclude the home page.